# Почему подключение по SSH восстанавливает связь с Apache на сервере?

Tags: linux, ssh

Сервер на Linux(Ubuntu) работает странно. На сервере работает Apache+PHP. Баз данных нет. Несколько раз в сутки (~10-20 раз) связь с сервером обрывается и на сайт невозможно попасть. Каждый обрыв длится ровно 10 минут. Во время простоя если зайти по SSH, связь с Апачем чудесным образом восстанавливается. Достаточно даже просто попытаться залогиниться, но telnet на 22 порт связь не восстановит.

Из-за чего может происходить такое поведение на сервере ?

p.s.
Нагрузки на трафик, диск и CPU  нет.

p.s.s
Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64)
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
PHP 5.5.9
SQL нет

Comment: Пожалуйста переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, или перейдите по ссылке - https://stackoverflow.com/ чтобы задать вопрос там :)

Comment: Перевел. Спасибо.

Comment: Переход в энергосберегающий режим?(шутка) При входе по ssh - там запросто может стоять команда которая запускает apache2. Проверяйте все скрипты на сервере для начала.

Comment: Через 10 минут сервер начинает отвечать нормально как ни в чем не бывало, без подключения по SSH

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что как бы вы не старались нас убедить что это мистика/магия/чудеса, то дело окажется в банальных скриптах - которые нужно проверять. Именно периодичность недоступности говорит о том, что выполняются какие то скрипты - и без подробностей вам ни чем не помогут.